# delete Cloud Firestore doc and Fire Storage file simultaneously

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a Cloud Firestore collection of documents (metadata about files that I've uploaded), and I have a bucket of those files in Firebase Storage.

I want to delete a given file using my Angular app.  I can delete the Firestore docs, but I'm unable to delete the corresponding files in Storage.

**Compile error:** `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';                      // I was experimenting with onPromise()
import { finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { StateService } from '../services/state.service';

// ...

export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

    isProgressVisible: boolean;

    constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage, public stateService: StateService) {
        this.isProgressVisible = false;
    }

    // ...    

    deleteFile(file): void {
        this.isProgressVisible = true;

        let storagePath = file.storagePath;                     // ex: 'uploads/1598066351161_myfile.txt'
        let delimiter = storagePath.indexOf('/');
        let docID = file.storagePath.substring(delimiter + 1);  // ex: '1598066351161_myfile.txt'

        let self = this;
 
        this.stateService.firebase.firestore().collection('files').doc(docID).delete().then(function () {
            console.log('cloud firestore doc deleted');

            let ref = self.storage.ref(storagePath);            // delete the file from Storage
            ref.delete().then(function () {
                console.log('file deleted from storage!');
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Error deleting file from storage:', error);
            });

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error('Error deleting cloud firestore doc:', error);
        });
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`this.stateService.firebase.firestore().collection('files').doc(docID).delete()` returns an observable which is not promise. You should either convert it to promise with `toPromise()` or use `subscribe` instead of `then`.

Check [this post](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html) for more insights.